# How can I get the width of each line of text in a label (the last line in particular)?

Tags: qt, qtquickcontrols

I have a label in my app that displays multiline text by setting `wrapMode: Text.WordWrap`. Is there any way to calculate the location (x and y) of the end of the last line of text in the label given a constrained width? In other words, if my label is constrained to be 100 px width and the last line of text (out of three lines) ends two-thirds of the way over, I'd like to be able to know that the end of the last line is at 66 px and that the third line starts with a y-value of 40 (if, for example, each line is 20 px high).

My requirement is that I need to place a little icon/image exactly at the end of the last line of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Label` doesn't appear to have any way to get this, but [TextArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textarea.html) has the method `positionToRectangle(position)` which gives the exact location of any character in the `text` and is exactly what I needed.